# Dynamic Class names (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, text, dynamic, addclass

```
<label>Hatchback    <input type="checkbox" name="" /></label>
<label>Bike     <input type="checkbox" name="" /></label>
<label>Sedan        <input type="checkbox" name="" /></label>
<label>Scooter      <input type="checkbox" name="" /></label>
<label>Coupe        <input type="checkbox" name="" /></label>
<label>SUV      <input type="checkbox" name="" /></label>
```

I'd like to grab the text in labels and apply them as class names.

This doesn't work:

```
var classname = $("fieldset.visual label").text();
$("fieldset.visual label").addClass(classname);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use each to apply just the text to that specific label as a class.

```
$('fieldset.visual label').each( function() {
    var className = $(this).text();
    $(this).addClass(className);
});
```

Comment: Almost perfect, just one thing: possible to lowercase all and remove spaces if found? Many thanks!

Comment: `className.toLowerCase()` and `className.replace(/ /g, '')` to get rid of spaces.